extract first sequence of numbers from a pandas column
I have imported a CSV into a pandas data frame; however, the column I need to use is freeform and in bad shape.
I need to extract the first series of numbers after the word NBU or the first series of numbers in the string. See some examples below:-
nbu 123456
NBU-123456
nbu/ 123456 blah12
123456
123456_123

All of the above should be cleaned to produce 123456. Note that the number of integers returned is based on how many are in a continual sequence; i.e., nbu12 3455 should only return 12.
I will then use something like this to fix the data:-
df['col'] = df['col'].str.


Check out [ask] for tips on how to write a good title. I've just improved this one for you.

A possible solution, which works as follows: It uses str.extract method to extract digits from the col column of df, where in r'(\d+)' the parentheses denote a capturing group, with \d+ meaning one or more digits.
df['col'].str.extract(r'(\d+)')

Output:
        0
0  123456
1  123456
2  123456
3  123456
4  123456


Is there a way, like in SQL, where you can state that it does not contain or is not in? For example, exclude anything containing NEX

Yes: df['col'].loc[~df['col'].str.contains('NEX')].
